# PHP validation in WordPress HTML Block

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to change an element in the WP Front End accordingly with a previous validation (if the user is logged in). Most concretly my code would be something like this:

```
<?php

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // html button
    } else {
       // different html button
    }
?>
```

To make it work I thought that a HTML block from WP would do the trick however is not working.
Does anyone know how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It actually works. I've just tried it. Just make sure you have a session you are logged in and one in a private window that you are not logged in. Besides that you can also check (after ensure they are logged in, to avoid errors) what kind of role the user is and decide accordingly.

```
$get_user_info = wp_get_current_user();
$role = $get_user_info->roles[0];
in_array($role, ['administrator', 'otherCustomRole']);
```

Comment: Hi @billybadass !! Thanks for your answer. My problem is not the code, but the way to implement it. I’m working with Elementor CMS so I used a custom html block to place this code. However this is not a valid format because I can see the <?php opening tags as plain text…

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to solved it.
I share my solution:

1. I created a php file with a custom function with the code in the same folder that my functions.php file. (I think it wasn’t necessary but I prefer to keep code independent)
2. I created a shortcode with the function I refer in the step 1.
3. Finally, I used the shortcode block to place the code in my front
   end.